# How to get this image src in javascript

Tags: javascript

For some reason , i need define the function in window.onload , any people know how to get this img src at window.onload

```
function addimagelink(imageelement){

   alert(imageelement.src);

}
```

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/boajay/rrve3058/)

Comment: your code is perfect just set jsfiddle option `No wrap in body` from left panel http://jsfiddle.net/rrve3058/5/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, for some reason i need use this function in window.onload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your image tag like this :

```
<img id="img1" src="someurl"  width="150" height="150" />
```

and then add an eventlistener :

```
     window.onload=function(){
          document.getElementById('img1').addEventListener('click',function addimagelink(evnt){
        alert(evnt.currentTarget.src);
        });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<Your html code>
<script>
alert(imageelement.getAttribute("src"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).onload(function(){
  alert($('#img1').attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    alert($('#YOUR_IMAGE_ID').attr('src'))
})
```

use jQuery